# Рисование растушеванной или полупрозрачной кистью в delphi. Как?

Tags: delphi, графика

Мой вариант - это просчитывать цвет каждого будущего пиксела нахождением среднего цвета между цветом фона и цветом кисти, чтобы получался плавный (растушеванный) переход от линии кисти к фону. Но это отнимает много процессорного времени.

[image]

Comment: http://vkontakte.ru/photo145392289_270547004
вот так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое понятие: гауссово размытие. Не слишком красивое с моей точки зрения, но довольно экономичное по ресурсам.

| G(u,v)= | 1 | ×e<sup>-(u<sup>2</sup>+v<sup>2</sup>)/(2σ<sup>2</sup>)</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2πσ<sup>2</sup> |

Comment: и что? я так понял мне нужно в буфере прорисовать линию, применить гаусово размытие к буферу, но ведь далее этот буфер нужно наложить на исходный image. А как это сделать?

Comment: Делается "сложением" матриц. Сложение в кавычках, потому что при разных фильтрах наложения будут разные функции для двух цветов. Размер матрицы равен диаметру кисти. Их количество зависит от длины линии, естественно. С большой вероятностью, в ближайшее время в делфи не появится поддержка CUDA, так что в любом случае рассчитывать будете не процессоре. Другое дело, 40000 интегеров(линия длиной 1000 пикселей, толщиной - 10, 32бита/пиксель) даже arm нормирует за крайне малое время.

И да, конечно, сначала рассчитывается размытая линия, а потом она накладывается на рисунок. Так быстрее.

Comment: А использовать шейдер для просчета каждого пиксела - не эффективней?

Comment: например HLSL

Answer (score 0):

Вот теперь понял ваш вопрос. 
Для подобных целей я вызываю внешнюю программу [**ImageMagick**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick)